# Tovelling a non-stick pan

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping

Should a metal pan with a non-stick coating be tovelled and if so, should it be with a bracha?  Does the non-stick coating mean that it isn't counted as a metal pan and therefore it doesn't require tevillah because that is the surface that comes into contact with the food?

Answer (score 7):

See Din Online [here](https://dinonline.org/2023/07/18/non-stick-frying-pan/):

> A non-stick frying pan, which is coated with Teflon needs tevila. There is controversy among the poskim if a bracha should be said on it or not. The reason being that Teflon is a type of plastic, which doesn’t need tevila. Since the actual kli would need tevila but the coating doesn’t, according to a number of poskim, we would tovel it but without a bracha. Other poskim say that since the Teflon is very thin, it is considered like a metal kli and therefore it would need tevila with a bracha. **What is best to do is to tovel it together with something else that needs a bracha, in order to avoid this question**. If this can’t be done, you can tovel it with a bracha.

> Sources:
>
> וע’ ספר טבילת כלים (פ”א סעי’ ו). בספר טבילת כלים (פי”א סעי’ צא) כתב לפי”ז שמחבת טפלון יש לטובלו בלא ברכה, וכ”כ  בס’ כוס של אליהו פרק א’ סעי’ ו’ “בזמננו מצוי מאד כלים שעשויים ממתכות אבל מצופים בטפלון (מין פלסטיק), או באמאייל (enamel) (שמבואר בשו”ת חת”ס (יו”ד רסי’ קיג) שדינו ככלי חרס), ויש להסתפק אם הציפוי בטל להמתכת או לא, בדומה לספק של כלי חרס המצופה באבר. ושמעתי ממו”ר הגרפ”א פאלק זצ”ל שצריכים טבילה בלי ברכה”. וכ”כ בס’ [מטבח הכשר](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422608975.html) (ארטסקרול, ריש עמ’ ת”ס, עמ’ תס”ב, עמ’ תע”ח, פרק י”ח הע’ כ”ח). ובס’ בין ישראל לעמים (פרק י”ג סעי’ ל”ו, [דברי דוד ח”א יו”ד סי’ ט’ אות ז’](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21994&st=&pgnum=119&hilite=)). ובשו”ת מנחת אשר (ח”ג סי’ סא אות א) כתב שפטור מטבילה כיון שסוף סוף אי ן המתכת נוגע באוכל (דלא כמהרש”ם, וצידד שאף המהרש”ם מודה כה”ג שאין הטפלון משמש למתכת כלל), אבל כתב שלמעשה לא נתברר לו ענין זה על בורי וולכן יש להטבילו בלי ברכה.
>
> אמנם מצד שני ע’  מבית לוי בענייני יו”ד עמ’ קמ”א אות ז’ “סירים ומחבתות המצופים טפלון טעונים טבילה בברכה”. וכן בספר מטבח כהלכה (פ”ה סעי’ ה) הביא מהגריש”א שכיון שהוא ציפוי דק מאד מאד הוי כצבע שבטל לכלי (כבסמוך) ואינו פוטרו מטבילה, ולכן יש לטובלו עם ברכה. וכן סבר הגר”ד פיינשטיין זצ”ל (קונ’ יד דודי עמ’ קמ”ד אות כ”ח, דפו”ח עמ’ קצ”ח אות כ”ח). ויבחל”ח הגר”נ קופשיץ שליט”א (קונ’ טהרת הכלים אות ד’) – “טבילה בברכה, דאין צד שהציפוי של הטפלון יפטור את עיקר הכלי שהוא ממתכת”. וע’ בשיעורי הלכה להגר” ש פעלדער (פ”ו אות ב) שלכתחילה יש לטובלו ביחד עם כלי אחר שודאי חייב בטבילה, ואם אינו יכול יש לברך על הטבילה.

Answer (score 6):

[According to the OU](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/tevilas-keilim-a-primer/), you tovel them but without a *beracha*:

> Glass-coated utensils, such as glazed chinaware, are a subject of
> debate among contemporary Poskim, but it has become common practice to
> **tovel them without a Bracha**. The same is true of porcelain enameled
> pots and utensils made from two or more materials, such as
> **Teflon-coated frying pans**.

Based on [Pitchei Teshuva YD 120:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.120.2?lang=bi).

Answer (score 0):

I asked a shailah and interestingly received a different answer to either of these.  I was told that there was a machlokes and he asked Dayan Berger (formerly of Manchester Beth Din), who said that actually there isn't a machlokes on modern non-stick coating - the machlokes is on older non-stick like ceramic, and that on modern pans, a bracha should be made.

Comment: It seems hard to accept that the OU cited in RabbiKaii's answer wasn't referring to "modern pans".

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought that as well, but I posted the answer here for completeness as that is the psak I was given

Comment: The reasoning might be related to what one Kashrut professional pointed out to me that the non stick coating contains glass